# React native Wordpress API not fetching posts

Tags: wordpress, react-native, fetch-api

Hello i recently just started learning react native. 
I am now trying to fetch data from a wordpress api with the following code with this exact api address but nothing loads up.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

    export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
    let dataURL = "https://click9ja.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          posts: response
        })
      })
  }
    render() {
    let posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
      return
      <View key={index}>
      <Text>Title: {post.title.rendered}</Text>
      </View>
    });
   return (
      <View>
        <Text>List Of Posts</Text>
        <Text>{posts}</Text>
      </View>
     )
  }
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What error message is shown in the browser devtools console?

Comment: I am using expo and there's no error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly wrap return value in parenthesis

```
let posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
      return (
      <View key={index}>
      <Text>Title: {post.title.rendered}</Text>
      </View> 
     );
    });
```

Secondly you cannot render variables in text tags. It should be something like this

```
<View>{varaible}</View>
```

Therefore, `<Text>{posts}</Text>` should just be `{post}`

Answer (score 0):

Fetch will have `GET` method as default when requesting to server. To set it to make a `POST` method or other methods you will need to add extra parameter in the fetch
In your case it will be

```
fetch('https://click9ja.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
});
```

Some API will need headers and body, please make sure to check the API Documentation before using it for understanding purpose.

For more information on Fetch in React native you can visit it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network)
For more information on What is API you can visit it [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-an-api-in-english-please-b880a3214a82)

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes i understand the Fetch vs Post argument. I am trying to GET data from the API so FETCH should work for me right now, what i don't understand is why the code above isn't fetching data from that particular API.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I have a wordpress API with a lot of data, the code above can't FETCH or GET the data. Do you understand me now?

Comment: try to send the request through Postman and see if it is fetch that is unable or the API that does not  return anything.

Comment: @sir-kosawa It works on postman, it also work when I visit the API directly on web browser. I also substituted my API with the API from react native documentation on networking it still doesn't work. I'm tired.

Comment: Well, i tried the request link and it work for me. I see that your original code is correct. Maybe you need to check if there is any error occured by doing catch error

The following code work for me
fetch('https://click9ja.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

`react-native log-android` to look at the console.log value